# Refresh issue when serving create-react-app with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

hope you are well!

I have an issue when trying to serve a create-react-app using an express.js server with Node.js backend.

For backend I have some routes defined to create an API with express and prisma, connecting to a database.

For frontend I used a react based app, Axios to fetch data from backend and react-router-dom V6 for client routing (BrowserRouter). To serve the files I created a build folder from React (in the .env file I have INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK set to false) with the npm run build script.

The files are generated correctly for the build and from the express app I attach these interface files with the separate route along with the API routes I have already defined. Everything goes okay, the interface opens, the API works but only if I navigate using components in the interface.

When I refresh a page in the browser, the application suddenly stops rendering, under a white screen. In the console area, in DevTools all kinds of loading errors appear which I will attach below with a print screen. The same thing happens if I try to navigate to another route in the browser bar.

I want to launch the application with express on an IP from a local machine. The server code is attached below with the required routes and middleware. So is the axios code and the routing in the interface. Has anyone else had problems like this?

```
import axios from 'axios';

const publicFetch = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://ABC.ABC.0.ABC:3002/api-v1"
});

export default publicFetch;
```

An this is the server code:

```
    'use strict';
    require('dotenv').config();
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const helmet = require('helmet');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const compression = require('compression');
    const SERVER_PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT;

    // ================================================
    // Server routes/controllers
    // ================================================

    const { createUser, getAllUsers, getSingleUser, updateUser, deleteUser, loginUser } = require('./routes/user-routes');
    const { createDepartment, getAllDepartments, getSingleDepartment, updateDepartmentData, deleteDepartment } = require('./routes/department-routes');

    const whitelist = ['ABC.ABC.0.ABC'];

    const corsOptions = {
        origin: function (origin, callback) {
          if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
          } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
          }
        }
      }

    // ================================================
    // Express App
    // ================================================

    const app = express();

    app.enable('trust proxy');

    // CORS
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));

    // JSON
    app.use(express.json());

    // ================================================
    // static serve from server and client build
    // ================================================

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));

    // compress responses
    // use compressions middleware for static files and res send
    app.use(compression());

    // ================================================
    // Middleware
    // ================================================

    // morgan logs middleware
    app.use(morgan('dev'));

    // helmet security headers
    app.use(helmet());

    // disable Express mention in reasponse header
    app.disable('x-powered-by');

    // ===============================================
    // User Endpoints
    // ================================================
    app.post('/api-v1/user', createUser);
    app.get('/api-v1/user', getAllUsers);
    app.get('/api-v1/user/:id', getSingleUser);
    app.put('/api-v1/user/:id', updateUser);
    app.delete('/api-v1/user/:id', deleteUser);
    app.post('/api-v1/user/login', loginUser);

    // ================================================
    // Department Endpoints
    // ================================================
    app.post('/api-v1/department', createDepartment);
    app.get('/api-v1/department', getAllDepartments);
    app.get('/api-v1/department/:id', getSingleDepartment);
    app.put('/api-v1/department/:id', updateDepartmentData);
    app.delete('/api-v1/department/:id', deleteDepartment);


    // Handles any requests that don't match the ones above

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
    });

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
    });

    // ================================================
    // Server start
    // ================================================

    app.listen(SERVER_PORT, "ABC.ABC.0.ABC", () => {
        console.log(`Server running and listening on port ${SERVER_PORT}...`);
    });
```

The errors that I get:
[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNmKp.png)